# How do I download / print pdfs in the new chrome integrated viewer?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Chrome recently started opening pdfs inside the browser. This is a great feature - it is fast, easy to read, and saves me from having to open it up in a separate browser.

However, it is not clear to me how I can save the pdf in a folder - using 'save as' creates broken files that Adobe and Mendeley can not read.

I am using Google Chrome in Ubuntu 10.04

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to save a different pdf file? I tried it and was able to save the file successfully by right clicking > Save As. Do you have a link to the PDF you want to save locally?

Is the pdf displayed in a frame? Try opening the frame in a new tab then save the file.

Comment: The save as points to an .html link; right-clicking on the pdf provides no option to save, the pdf is displayed in a frame, and it doesn't help to open it to a new tab. I have attached an image to the original question

Comment: try right clicking in the grey area left or right to the pdf.

Comment: @weltenwanderer neither of those work...

Comment: can you locate the source for the PDF and just insert that into the URL?

Comment: When I look at the screenshot I think there may be some kind of drm around that pdf display to prevent that.

Comment: @ngen the PDF url is in the browser. I can locate it and open it in a browser, but when I want to print it there are no controls to do so.

Comment: I believe Weltenwanderer is correct. Can you try a different browser and view the URL? Don't think it's a Chrome issue anymore.

Comment: @ngen saving / printing the same document works fine in Firefox; the adobe reader controls appear in the browser window.  And it happens with most pdfs, not only at this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Mac, hitting Command-S (or using menu File, Save Page As...) works just fine. Likewise printing works fine using Command-P (or menu File, Print). On Windows that would be Ctrl-S and Ctrl-P then.

However, your screenshot is using a HTML `<frameset>`: one fixed upper frame with some Wiley information, and a lower frame with the PDF. Clicking "Open Frame in New Window" in the lower frame gets you a window with just the PDF, in which Ctrl-S will work. But hoping for an easier way, I created [an example](http://jsbin.com/epeyo4) of such frameset that does *not* require one to log in. But in that example, in Chrome on a Mac, I have no clue how to avoid having to use "Open Frame in New Window" first. Like: clicking in the frame before hitting Ctrl-S or Ctrl-P does *not* tell my Chrome which part I want to save or print.

Comment: what does it mean that my screenshot is using a HTML `<frameset>` ?

Comment: `Ctrl+P` works; `Ctrl-S` attempts to save the page as html (in Ubuntu)

Comment: @David, you're seeing two parts: one fixed upper frame with that Wiley information, and a lower frame with the PDF. You'll need to tell Chrome which part you're referring to. Like when viewing the source of such page, or when saving or printing, you'll most often have some *"...this frame"* options. Like "Print this frame". In your screenshot I see "Open Frame in New Window". Doing that will get you a window with just the PDF (in which Ctrl-S might work), but I guess there must be an easier way. (I cannot access the URL you're using.)

Comment: you are correct; open frame in new tab allowed me to use `Ctrl-S` to save.

Comment: Okay, @David, then that should work for any site that does not use a `<frameset>` (so: for most sites). For frames, I created [an example](http://jsbin.com/epeyo4), but have no clue how to avoid having to use "Open Frame in new Window" first...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because that PDF is in a "frame". In the right click menu select "Open Frame in New Window".

When you have 'just' a PDF opened (e.g. [this one](http://www.mei.org.uk/files/papers/c307ja_02c76.pdf)) you can right click and press either "Save As..." or "Print...". The resulting file opened fine for me in Ubuntu default application Evince, and also in Adobe Reader.

[image: Screenshot]