# Disabling Chrome's built-in PDF viewer

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, pdf-reader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop PDFs from displaying inside Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/30850/stop-pdfs-from-displaying-inside-google-chrome)

Chrome now has a built-in pdf viewer, and it's one of the worst I've seen. You can't even save the file you're viewing! Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: I'm not surprised you didn't find it. I only found it because I knew it existed.

Comment: As an aside: right-click should give you a Save As option: [How do I download / print pdfs in the new chrome integrated viewer?](http://superuser.com/questions/224546/how-do-i-download-print-pdfs-in-the-new-chrome-integrated-viewer)

Comment: @Arjan: It doesn't always work, sometimes it saves the surrounding page instead.

Comment: @cool-RR, sure, but that is all handled in the other question I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://techdows.com/2010/11/how-to-disable-chrome-pdf-viewer-in-google-chrome.html (first google result for 'disable chrome pdf viewer')

> 1. Type about:plugins in Chrome’s Omnibox and press enter.
> 2. Click “Disable” for “Chrome PDF Viewer”.
> 3. Chrome PDF Viewer will be disabled and Installed PDF Reader plug-in will be activated and from now on PDF files will be opened in Chrome by that PDF Reader.

Answer (score 1):

If you type `about:plugins` in your address bar, you can open the plugin management page.

From there, you can disable the built in viewer, **Chrome PDF Viewer**, and enable whichever viewer you prefer (presumably **Adobe Acrobat**).